# Find a domain (open and connected set) in which $f(z) = (z-2)arg_0 (z)$ is continuous.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find a domain (open and connected set) in which $f(z) = (z-2)arg_0 (z)$ is continuous.
>
> **Note:** $$arg_\phi(z) = arg(\phi),~~~~ \text{where }\phi < arg(z) \le \phi + 2\pi$$

\begin{align}f(z) &= (z-2)arg_0(z) \\ &=(z-2)arg(z), ~ \text{where } 0<arg(z)\le 2\pi \end{align}

Now note that $(z-2)$ is continuous over the whole of $\mathbb C$.

$arg_0(z)$ is discontinuous at the branch point $z=0$ and along the branch cut $Re(z)>0$, that is, the positive real-axis.

Hence we have that $f(z)= (z-2)arg_0(z)$ is continuous on every open set that does not contain $z=0$ or the positive real axis.

How can I create a domain from this?

Would it be $$S= \{ z \in \mathbb C : Re(z)<0 \}$$
As this would be an open and connected set and hence a domain?

Comment: It would be, but probably you're expected to find the largest domain on which the function is continuous. What is the largest open set on which it is continuous?

Comment: @DanielFischer - I am not sure. This was the only open set that I could think of?

Comment: What is the set of points where the function is continuous?

Comment: @DanielFischer - I cannot seem to see any other set where it is continuous. Can you please show me how you get it?

Comment: I just saw, you wrote "along the branch cut, $\operatorname{Re} (z) > 0$, that is, the positive real-axis". The formula doesn't say the same thing as the words (and the words are correct). That may indicate a certain misunderstanding. $\operatorname{Re} z > 0$ describes the right half-plane, not the positive real axis. If your $\operatorname{Re} z < 0$ is meant to describe the complement of the branch cut, you mean the right set, you just didn't describe it correctly. Can you describe the set you mean in words?

Comment: Not correct. You wrote that $z-2$ is continuous everywhere, and that $\arg_0$ is discontinuous at $0$ and on the positive real axis - that is, it is discontinuous on $[0,+\infty)$. Assuming you are aware that $\arg_0$ is continuous everywhere else, you know that $f$ is continuous at all points not in $[0,+\infty)$, since it's the product of two continuous functions there. That set is $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{ t \in \mathbb{R} : t \geqslant 0\}$. Does that look like an open set?

Comment: @DanielFischer -  $S = \{ z = x + iy : x<0 \}$ ?

Comment: That's again the left half-plane, $S = \{ z : \operatorname{Re} z < 0\}$. That is a domain on which $f$ is continuous, but not the largest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27457/discussion-between-djs-and-daniel-fischer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a thought, it might be easier to write your domain as follows. Let

$$
P = \{z\in\mathbb{C}\,:\,\text{Re}(z) \geq 0,\,\text{Im}(z) = 0\} 
$$

Then $f$ is continuous on $S = \mathbb{C}\setminus P$, which is certainly open and connected.